# onCreate is called when back button in action bar is pressed

Tags: android

My app has 2 main activities, one of which is launched from the main activity.

I'm wondering why `onCreate()` is being called when I return to the main activity after pressing the back button on the navigation bar of the subactivity.

This does not happen if I press the physical back button.

Comment: the system could have killed your activity and that could explain, without seeing a single line of code, why onCreate is called again

Comment: post the code for clarity

Comment: @SunilKumarSahoo which part of the code, in particular?

Comment: @blackbelt I was thinking that could be the case. But what's strange is that pressing the hardware back buttons reliably restore my previous activity without going through `onCreate()` while using the back button on the navigation bar reliably calls `onCreate()` every time.

Answer (score -1):

"button on the navigation bar" - what code are you using when you press this button to launch main activity?
If you are doing something like:

```
Intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

then obviously it will create a new Activity and start with the OnCreate method.

Comment: No, the back button is automatically generated when the activity parent is specified in the manifest.

Comment: it's better you will post the code. Because I also doubt that you are making a new intent in your code just like @Arnab presented.